# which jboss-javaee-6.0 version on jboss 7.1.0

Tags: java, maven, jboss, version, pom.xml

i create a example maven application and deployed it to jboss 7.1.0 thunder.

in the pom.xml is the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

which version of jboss-javaee-6.0 should i use on jobss 7.1.0? there are also other versions available(http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.spec/jboss-javaee-6.0).

thanks and greets

mp5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer in the jboss doc.
 https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Maven+POM+Versions+Checklist
this is a version list for writing quickstarts on jboss 7.1

Answer (score 1):

It completely depends on your requirement for example, which version of servlets/JSF (or) some other API you want use. If you are starting fresh development, may be going with latest version is always good.

Comment: thanks for your answer. with jboss-javaee-6.0 1.0.0.Final version, I get jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final as provided dependency. but in the jboss modules folder is only jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec-1.0.1.Final. is there a version of jboss-javaee-6.0 which has the same versions like provided on jboss as 7.1.0?

Comment: You need to download those jars from Jboss and replace/create new modules in server.